# Get Only Camera Captured Images

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to write a module to get the path of only camera captured images. I found that directory dcim method which returns dcim directory path but i want to know that which is camera captured image path or is there any camera intent to get this. Please help... My code is look like this :

```
public static File readPathImages()
    {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        if (path.exists()) 
        {
            File test1 = new File(path, "Camera/");
            if (test1.exists())
                path = test1;
            else {
                File test2 = new File(path, "100ANDRO/");
                if (test2.exists())
                    path = test2;
                else {
                    File test3 = new File(path, "100MEDIA/");
                    if (test3.exists()) {
                        path = test3;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: as you said, inside `DCIM`, there is a `Camera` folder, images captured by the camera  are stored there..

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: but in DCIM there is many folders like : if you download any image from facebook then it is place in this folder or many different folders in it. So my question is how i know that only camera captured image folder path? In HTC phones there is 100Media in place of Camera folder.